# Approach for Vuex to update state - after - CRUD operations

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Let's suppose I have a collection of books retrieved by a Vuex action called `fetchBooks` (this action commit the `SETBOOKS` mutation to change state).

When I dispatch the action `remove` to remove a book, I have two options:

1) Send request to the API to delete the resource and then dispatch `fetchBooks` to reload the books listing.

2) Send request to the API to delete the resource and then commit the  `REMOVE` mutation to remove the book from state, without any additional HTTP request.

The first seems more easy, I can use the same technique for add/update/delete, with the price of doing an additional request to reload the listing.

The second is more cheap (no additional request), but require more logic to handle state for each add/update/delete case.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes, the second one seems cheaper but you have to make sure that the update is done on backend

Comment: In your delete call get the resource as the response. then reload the state.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 2.
In the general practice "getBooks" could be a huge array, and it is better not to requery the data from the DB when you already have it locally.

Just make sure you are deleting the book inside a try catch block, so if the delete doesn't go in the backend, you should alert the user.